# PDO Select statement returning 2 dimentional array, how do i print one value from that array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

In my project i am trying to select an id field and a varchar field from a database and i want to return a 2 dimentional array containing the id fields and the varchar fields.This is what i have done:

```
        foreach($dbh->query("SELECT status, post_id FROM status WHERE user_id = " . $user_id) as $row_all){
            $ret_array[] = $row_all; 
        }


        return @$ret_array;
```

When i print the value on another page:

```
foreach ($all_stats as $key => $value) {
    foreach ((array)$value as $post_id => $status) {
        echo $status;

    }
}
```

When it is printed on the page i get:

"Second post" 
1
1

I would like to print only value that is held in the status part of the array. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already use PDO, one should consider using PDO-Statements.
After having prepared the query and executed the statements, it's results can be diretly received by `$array = $Statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. That returns an associative array like the following :

```
[0] => ID => 1
    => Status => 0

[1] => ID => 2
    => Status => 1
```

Then, you can loop through that array like shown here :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    echo $array[$i]['status'];
}
```

Comment: What do you have against `foreach`?

Comment: And `$i < count($array)` is the more usual way to express the looping condition.

Comment: I wanted to give an alternative approach and some Information about PDO statements. Thank you for the feedback, I must have forgotten some very obvious things :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the row is an associative array, just index it with the key you want:

```
foreach ($all_stats as $row) {
    echo $row['status'];
}
```

Comment: This is whats returned when i try that:Warning: Illegal string offset 'status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bloggie\Bloggie_Profile.php on line 93

Comment: That means that `$all_stats` is an array of strings, not a 2-dimensional array.